# Excel Userform: Delete row when multiple criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have 2 sheet on my excel workbook.
1 is Stock In sheet and 1 is Stock Out sheet.

I wish to store the information in Stock Out sheet when the data is found in Stock In.

Stock In sheet:

[image]

Stock Out sheet:

[image]

For example, the Stock Out sheet only will able to accept the data when the PT# and the Rack is tally with the detail in Stock In sheet.

As below will be the code for my delete button inside my userform:

```
 Private Sub TrackOut_Click()
  Sheets("Stock Out").Activate
  Dim cDelete As VbMsgBoxResult
               With Me
                        If Len(.TextBox1.Value) * Len(.PT.Value) *      
   Len(.Rack2.Value) * _
            Len(.Operator2.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please Complete All Fields Before Submit"
    Else

    cDelete = MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to delete this record", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Track Out")
    If cDelete = vbYes Then
       If Sheets("Stock In").Columns(2).Find(What:=PT.Text) Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "No stock inventory for this PT#"
          Exit Sub
       End If
       eRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Cells(eRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
        Cells(eRow, 2).Value = PT.Text
        Cells(eRow, 3).Value = Rack2.Text
        Cells(eRow, 4).Value = Operator2.Text

        Else

        If cDelete = vbNo Then
        Unload Me
        End If
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it will just delete the PT# but will not check whether the Rack is tally with the PT# or not.

Answer (score 0):

OK - this is what I understand and what the code adjustment below does:

Operator completes a userform and inputs Date, PT#, Rack No and Operator.  This gets looked-up in 'Stock In' sheet (all fields must match). If operator confirms then the record gets transferred to 'Stock Out' sheet on next available row and deleted from 'Stock In' sheet and other records moved up.

If you only want say two fields to match (userform and 'Stock In') then see the code for the adjustments to make: commented as '**

```
Private Sub TrackOut_Click()

Sheets("Stock Out").Activate
Dim cDelete As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim fndItm As Range
Dim orow As Long, irow As Long
Dim reqStock As String, itmStock As String
Dim stockArr(4) As String
    With Me
        If Len(.TextBox1.Value) * Len(.PT.Value) * Len(.Rack2.Value) * Len(.Operator2.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please Complete All Fields Before Submit."
        Else
            'collect requested (userform) data
            '** reqStock should include those fields you require to match with Stock In record
            '** currently set to check all fields
            reqStock = .TextBox1.Value & .PT.Value & .Rack2.Value & .Operator2.Value
            Set fndItm = Sheets("Stock In").Columns(2).Find(What:=PT.Text)
                If Not fndItm Is Nothing Then
                    'if PT# found collect stock row data
                    With Sheets("Stock In")
                        irow = fndItm.Row
                        stockArr(0) = Format(.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                        stockArr(1) = .Cells(irow, 2).Value
                        stockArr(2) = .Cells(irow, 3).Value
                        stockArr(3) = .Cells(irow, 4).Value
                        '** itmStock should include those fields you require to match with userform fields
                        '** these should match reqStock
                        '** currently set to check all fields
                        itmStock = stockArr(0) & stockArr(1) & stockArr(2) & stockArr(3)
                    End With
                    'compare requested (userfrom) data with Stock In data
                    If reqStock = itmStock Then
                        cDelete = MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to delete this record from stock?", vbYesNo) ' + vbDefaultButton2, _
                        "Track Out")
                            If cDelete = vbYes Then
                                'xfer record to Stock Out sheet
                                With Sheets("Stock Out")
                                    orow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                                    .Range(.Cells(orow, 1), .Cells(orow, 4)) = stockArr
                                End With
                                'delete record from Stock In sheet
                                With Sheets("Stock In")
                                    .Range(.Cells(irow, 1), .Cells(irow, 4)).Delete xlShiftUp
                                End With
                            End If
                        'clear userform fields for next entry
                        .TextBox1.Value = ""
                        .PT.Value = ""
                        .Rack2.Value = ""
                        .Operator2.Value = ""
                    Else
                        MsgBox "PT# found but requested information does not match."
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "No stock inventory for this PT#."
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```